# JQuery Mobile events does not fire after ajax call

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile

I'm JQM newbe and I'm using it for our ASP.NET MVC 4 project. Here's a simplified version of code that I'm using:

Controller:

`public ActionView ShowModel()
{
    return View("ShowModel", new Model());
}`

View (ShowModel.cshtml Javascript):

```
<script>
    $('#page').bind('pageinit', function() {
        $('#spanSubmit').click(function () { $('form').submit(); });            
    });
<script>
<form action="@Url.Action("ShowModel")">
    <span id="spanSubmit">Submit</span>
</form>
```

After AJAX query I can't fire form submitting again also no other callbacks that were attached in `pageinit` callback are working. 
Everything starts working when I'm adding `data-ajax="false"` to form tag. But I really want it to work with AJAX, so can anyone explain me what should I do.

I know that my question was asked several times but I still can't make this page work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried delegation? like this? `$(document).on("pageinit", "#page", function(){..});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to look more into documentation and HTML code after AJAX call. After AJAX completed JQM creates an additional page with same id. So calling `$('#page').bind` fails because there are two pages now with `page` id.